# Solution verification of an approximation of an integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, asymptotics

I have to show that
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} e^{-xt} \sin t dt \approx \dfrac{1}{x^2}.
\end{align}
It is well known that the above integral belongs to as subtype known as *Laplace Integrals* and to approximate them we use a method called *Watson's Lemma*. I just wanted to know if I nailed it down correctly.

The method generally is to observe that only the leading terms in this integral have a big impact on the outcome (hence, asymptotics) so we take
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} e^{-xt} \sin t dt = \int_{0}^{\epsilon} e^{-xt} \sin t dt + \int_{\epsilon}^{1} e^{-xt} \sin t dt.
\end{align}

The second integral can be made obsolete, since for $x \to \infty $ it's exponentially small. To do this, we take
\begin{align}
 \int_{\epsilon}^{1} e^{-xt} \sin t dt < \int_{\epsilon}^{1}1 e^{-xt}dt \quad \quad \quad \text{since of course } \sin x <x, \ x \in (0,1)
\end{align}
which as mentioned above for $x \to \infty $ yields $0$. We will now write the remaining integral in the form of a powerseries for $\sin x$, namely:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \dfrac{1}{(2n+1)!} \int_{0}^{\epsilon}e^{-xt} t^{2n+1}dt.
\end{align}

As a last step, we will rewrite the integral above as a $Gamma$ function. To do that we take
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\epsilon}e^{-xt} t^{2n+1}dt &= \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-xt} t^{2n+1}dt - \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\epsilon}e^{-xt} t^{2n+1}dt}_{\text{exponentially small, goes to zero}}\\
&= \dfrac{\Gamma (2n+2)}{x^{2n+2}}
\end{align}
and what we are left with is precisely the Gamma function.

Putting it all together, we get that
\begin{align}
I(x) &\approx \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \dfrac{1}{(2n+1)!} \cdot \dfrac{\Gamma (2n+2)}{x^{2n+2}}\\
&\approx \sum_{n}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \dfrac{1}{x^{2n+2}}
\end{align}
and the expected result stems from letting only the first term through, namely letting $n=0$.

Is my method correct?

Comment: Concluding that $\int_{0}^{\epsilon}e^{-xt} t^{2n+1}dt = \frac{\Gamma (2n+2)}{x^{2n+2}}$ is incorrect. Also, you have to subtract the integral from $\varepsilon$ to $\infty$ and not from $0$ to $x$. In fact, there is no need to introduce $\varepsilon$ in the first place.

Comment: First off, I would observe that the asymptotic expression of the integral warrants the $\epsilon$ approach.

Comment: Second, please completely write the integral expression you want.

Comment: And why is $\int_{0}^{\epsilon}e^{-xt} t^{2n+1}dt = \frac{\Gamma (2n+2)}{x^{2n+2}}$ wrong?

Comment: What if you do not introduce $\varepsilon$? The whole process would still work. Second, $
\int_0^\varepsilon  {}  = \int_0^\infty  {}  - \int_\varepsilon ^\infty  {} $ and not $
\int_0^\varepsilon  {}  = \int_0^\infty  {}  - \int_0^x {}$. Third, $
\int_0^\varepsilon  {e^{ - xt} t^{2n + 1} dt}  \ne \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - xt} t^{2n + 1} dt}  = \frac{{\Gamma (2n + 2)}}{{x^{2n + 2} }}$.

Comment: On the second note, you are correct, it was a typo due to my speed of typing

Comment: @Gary on the third note, I kinda get what you are saying. What do you recommend me changing?

Comment: The correction to the second one is still not correct. For the third one you may write the final result as $\frac{{\Gamma (2n + 2)}}{{x^{2n + 2} }} + \mathcal O(e^{ - x(\varepsilon /2)} )$ since $$
\int_\varepsilon ^\infty  {e^{ - xt} t^{2n + 1} dt}  = \int_\varepsilon ^\infty  {e^{ - x(t/2)} e^{ - x(t/2)} t^{2n + 1} dt}  \le e^{ - x(\varepsilon /2)} \int_\varepsilon ^\infty  {e^{ - xt/2} t^{2n + 1} dt}  = \mathcal O(e^{ - x(\varepsilon /2)} ).
$$ To see that $\varepsilon$ is not necessary, play the whole game with $\varepsilon=1$.

Comment: Watson's lemma is basically just a special case of Laplace's method, which is a special case of the method of steepest descent. I suggest you learn about these.

Comment: @Gary I welcome your input. I will take a look at the comments maybe tomorrow and come back to you.

Comment: What @K.defaoite says is correct, but you have to find a suitable source. Many sources discuss only the simple saddle case, and obviously $t\mapsto t$ does not have any saddles. The Watson lemma is a special case of a Lapalce-type integral with linear dependence at the endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a straight answer, you can observe that indefinite integral equals to
$$
-(e^{-t x} (\cos(t) + x \sin(t)))/(1 + x^2)
$$
and the definite integral behaves in the infinity like $1/x^2$, indeed.

Comment: @algevristis Sorry, I misunderstood your sentence "The only reason I am asking is basically because I was expecting a straight answer and not one correlated with a series expression".

Comment: No you are also right. I framed it wrong in my post. Will try to fix.

Comment: @algevristis So I will delete my answer, as useless in the present formulation of the question, right?

Comment: No keep it its ok